# Android ROOM Get the autogenerated primarykey id when inserting rows

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I need to get the 'id' value that was automatically generated whenever I add a new row in my database using the following functions.

#### TaskItem.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "task_item_table")
class TaskItem(
    // Date Info
    @ColumnInfo(name = "hour") var hour: Int, // Hours
    @ColumnInfo(name = "minutes") var minutes: Int, // Minutes
    @ColumnInfo(name = "totalMinutes") var totalMinutes: Int, // HoursId (total of minutes, for sorting)
    // Sound Info
    @ColumnInfo(name = "withMusic") var withMusic: Boolean, // With Music at the end
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isActive") var isActive: Boolean, // If it will ring
    // Sound Volume
    // @ColumnInfo(name = "volume") var volume: Int, // If it will ring

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
)
```

As you can see the primary key will always have an unique integer.

#### TaskItemDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface TaskItemDao
{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_item_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun allTaskItems(): Flow<MutableList<TaskItem>>

    @Query("UPDATE task_item_table SET isActive=:newActiveValue WHERE isActive=:isActive")
    suspend fun setAllAlarmsTaskItem(isActive: Boolean, newActiveValue: Boolean)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem)
}
```

#### TaskItemRepository.kt

```
class TaskItemRepository(private val taskItemDao: TaskItemDao)
{
    val allTaskItems: Flow<MutableList<TaskItem>> = taskItemDao.allTaskItems()


    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem)
    {
        taskItemDao.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun updateTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem)
    {
        taskItemDao.updateTaskItem(taskItem)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem)
    {
        taskItemDao.deleteTaskItem(taskItem)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun setAllAlarmsTaskItem(isActive: Boolean, newActiveValue: Boolean)
    {
        taskItemDao.setAllAlarmsTaskItem(isActive, newActiveValue)
    }
}
```

#### TaskViewModel.kt

```
class TaskViewModel(private val repository: TaskItemRepository): ViewModel()
{
    val taskItems: LiveData<MutableList<TaskItem>> = repository.allTaskItems.asLiveData()
    private lateinit var taskViewModel: TaskViewModel


    fun addTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
    }
    
    fun updateTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.updateTaskItem(taskItem)
    }

    fun deleteTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.deleteTaskItem(taskItem)
    }

    fun setAllAlarmsTaskItem(isActive: Boolean, newActiveValue: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.setAllAlarmsTaskItem(isActive, newActiveValue)
    }

    fun setCompleted(taskItem: TaskItem) = viewModelScope.launch {

        repository.updateTaskItem(taskItem)
    }


}

class TaskItemModelFactory(private val repository: TaskItemRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory
{
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T
    {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(TaskViewModel::class.java))
            return TaskViewModel(repository) as T

        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

#### NewTaskSheet.kt

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val activity = requireActivity()

    binding.tvGuardar.setOnClickListener {
        saveAction()
    }

}


private fun saveAction(){

    // ... some more code
    if (taskItem == null)
    {
        val newTask = TaskItem(hour, minutes, totalMinutes, withMusic, isActive)
        taskViewModel.addTaskItem(newTask)
        // Here is where i need to get the id value, so i can passed to my alarm service

    }
    // ... some more code
        alarmService.setRepetitiveAlarm(timeInMilis, musicHour, musicMinutes, withMusic)

}
```

I have tried to use the following functions with no success:
So basically i just returns in every function.

#### TaskViewModel.kt

This is the function that I think is the one causing the problems because is the one that makes the program crash:

```
fun addTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long {
    // return@async repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
    return runBlocking(viewModelScope.coroutineContext) {
        return@runBlocking repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
    }
}

// Also tried with this function.
// This one didn't crashed it just return some sort of string that
// didn't contained the id that I was looking for
fun addTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Deferred<Long> = viewModelScope.async {
    return@async repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
}
```

#### TaskItemRepository.kt

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long
{
    return taskItemDao.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
}
```

#### TaskItemDao.kt

I read that by returning Long it automatically returns the value of the primary key.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long
```

I'm expecting to be able to have the 'id' value (primarykey) that was given to the corresponding created row so I can use it as my requestCode for my pendingIntents.

```
private fun getPendingIntent(intent: Intent) =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        0, // Here is where the id should be
        intent,
        //PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

    )
```

Or is there another strategy of correctly handling "requests codes"?

My app is an alarm clock so every alarm must have a unique code that will be saved in the database to later be able to delete the created alarm.

Comment: You are not catching the automatically generated Long value from TaskViewModel addTaskItem function. Catch the returning value and use as the unique identifier

Comment: `fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long` the return value is what you need.

Comment: My main question is how can i return the Long value from TaskViewModel, when i add `val rValue = repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)`  and in next line `return@launch rValue` Android Studio warns me "Required Unit found Long".

Answer (score 0):

In TaskItemDao, return the ID from the insert

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long
```

In TaskItemRepository, return the ID again

```
suspend fun insertTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long
{
    return taskItemDao.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
}
```

In TaskViewModel you can add the item, get the ID, and return it.
Note that to return from a coroutine scope, you'll have to mark the function as suspend, and use the callers context. This enforces that the function is called from a coroutine scope.

```
suspend fun addTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem): Long = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    return@withContext repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
}
```

Note the `Dispatchers.IO`, you always want to specify that when making Room calls to a DAO method that doesn't return a Flow.
The crash you saw was likely because of using Room on the main thread which is not allowed (and which IO prevents).

From the UI layer you can call the new ViewModel function using the lifecycle scope of the Fragment

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val newTaskID = taskViewModel.addTaskItem(newTask)
}
```

Whichever code needs the newTaskID will go in the coroutine scope.

I recommend reading up on [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) and checking out the [additional resources](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/additional-resources). Having a strong understanding of async concepts is important when using Room.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but addTaskItem isn't being called from a coroutine scope. I edited `NewTaskSheet.kt` so that you can better understand the code. Because Android Studio now throws me this error:  Suspend function 'addTaskItem' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function. I Convert my "SaveAction" function to a suspend and now when i call "SaveAction" function it throws the warning Suspend function 'saveAction' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function.

Comment: @lapdoggo I added some more explanation that should help. At some point you'll have to switch from sync to async code. Tagging more functions as suspend just moves the problem up the call stack. A suspend function can only be called from a coroutine (async) context, as the function is expected to perform async work.

Answer (score 0):

Call your repository method `insertTaskItem`  in the `viewmodelScope` and save the returned id in a liveData or stateFlow, then you can observe the liveData from your view. thats what I understood from the question, if you don't need the id from the view, then just deal with it in the viewModel

```
class TaskViewModel(private val repository: TaskItemRepository): ViewModel()
{
    private val _myId = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    val myId : LiveData<Long> get() = _myId

    fun addTaskItem(taskItem: TaskItem) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _myId.value = repository.insertTaskItem(taskItem)
            // or you can save the id in a variable here and do your work
        }
    }

}
```

note that you don't need to use `withContext` to change the thread to IO as Room automatically handles this and all of the dao suspend functions are safe to be called from the main thread.